# Auctioning off Kibbudim in Shul

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Question: what are the halachic permissabities and downsides to shul auctions for Kibbudim on Shabbos and Yom Tov?

Comment: Downside #1 someone has to memorize who paid how much for each kibbud since you can't write anything down

Comment: Hi Rafi, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! This question is likely to be marked as a duplicate of another question we have on the site, which I will link below. Hope it helps answer your questions!